# Helping a choking person

Tags: women, non-mahram, helping

I live in a sharing house so the door next to me is a women who’s not married and she lives alone. My friend also lives in the same sharing house and we all have different rooms I don’t talk to the women beside or even see her. But once my friend was outside and the women next to my room started choking so I had to help her I could have called the doctor but I was panicking that I did not think of that even so I went to her than I pressed her chest but then she had fainted so I had to give her a mouth to mouth to save her.
QUESTION: is it ok to press a women breast or chest and give her a mouth to mouth if needed to save her like in this situation

Answer (score 2):

If there was a woman around who could do abdominal thrusts/CPR then you shouldn't. BUT if there wasn't another woman around then it was perfectly fine for you to do so (as long as you "touch" only as much as needed and no more than that).. inshaAllah. Allah (ﷻ) has always given exception to dire situations, saying "except for one is forced" etc.. [eg, in Qur'an [6:119](https://quran.com/6/119) and [16:106](https://quran.com/16/106), etc]. When a person is choking, there is very little time before oxygen deprivation damages the brain or leads to death. Therefore, your immediate response in trying to save her life was good.  But **always** make sure to call professional emergency responders along with that.